# Chart.Mvc scale begin at 0 - Nullable bool property remains null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, chart.js

I am using the Chart.js .NET wrapper for use in ASP.NET MVC (https://github.com/martinobordin/Chart.Mvc), to generate a line chart of a list of temperatures and timestamps.
The data is already being displayed, but the temperature axis doesn't look pretty yet. I want this axis to **always start at 0 degrees**, so I tried to set ChartConfiguration.ScaleBeginAtZero (nullable bool) to false.

However, this **property always remains null**, both before and after I step over this line using the debugger. It is not the only property that behaves like this.

This is the content of my view:

```
@{
    const string Canvas = "LineChart";
    var complexChart = new LineChart();

    List<string> labels = new List<string>();
    ComplexDataset dataset = new ComplexDataset
    {
        Label = "Temperatures",
        FillColor = "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
        StrokeColor = "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        PointColor = "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        PointStrokeColor = "#fff",
        PointHighlightFill = "#fff",
        PointHighlightStroke = "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    };

    foreach (var measurement in Model)
    {
        labels.Add(measurement.Timestamp.ToShortTimeString());
        dataset.Data.Add(measurement.Temperatuur);
    }

    complexChart.ComplexData.Labels.AddRange(labels);
    complexChart.ComplexData.Datasets.Add(dataset);

    complexChart.ChartConfiguration.ScaleBeginAtZero = false;
}
<canvas id="@Canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

@Html.CreateChart(Canvas, complexChart)
```

Any idea what's happening here? The ChartConfiguration object is read-only, but its properties aren't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this was a bug. Now fixed using version 1.0.2.